# Arduino at the movies

Tags: discussion

I was watching a rather cheesy disaster movie this evening (a terrible film - [Collision Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1887703/) - very formulaic, I could write the script blindfold) and spotted an Arduino (well, some red Arduino Uno clone, probably R2 looking at the location of the reset button) in one of the props.  It forms, supposedly, part of the communication system of a space ship...

[image]

Does anyone else know of any instances of an Arduino or an Arduino Clone being used as a prop in a movie?

---

Oh, and while kind of on the subject, I recognise this PCB from somewhere. It's from the same film, but I know the PCB. They're normally in a rack of loads of them (in the film they are, too, but backwards). I swear I've seen it before somewhere from some teardown maybe.  Anyone have any hints?

[image]

Comment: The 2nd image looks like telco equipment.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about a POTS line card, but it doesn't have the right connectors. From what I see it's only got a card edge connector, and all the POTS equipment comes in rectangular racks.

Comment: Yes, I just immediately saw the multiple small transformers without big caps and other power-supply components and imagine they are for telecom transmission, plus the card looks like standard telco interface cards (http://www.msln.net/guides/images/equipment/westell.jpg) with the exception that the card-edge is on the "bottom" rather than the "back", taking the LEDs as being on the "front".

Comment: It might be that they are reminding me of the cards in a data IO programmer (https://youtu.be/9MIzbTpdt80) purely from the shape.

Comment: Someone on Electronics SE might recognize the second board. I don't, personally.

Comment: They may. I don't want to disturb them with my inane ramblings though. The question of what that board is is rather unimportant - just curious. The main question is, has anyone else spotted an Arduino in a film?

Comment: I decided I should start a fandom wiki on the topic of PCBs in bad films.  https://movie-circuits.fandom.com/

Comment: It somewhat reminds me of those shutterstock images of "people doing electronics" as in https://imgur.com/gallery/OQndy

Picture Nr. 4 also has an Arduino in it. Or the replica/fake bombs used to add extra game elements to airsoft matches. As in https://www.hackster.io/draymond/prop-bomb-for-paintball-airsoft-8ea257

Answer (score 3):

Not an Arduino, but quite humorous anyway...

This is from [Christmas Icetastrophe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3993802/), another really bad disaster flick (yes, I am a fan of really really bad movies - they are so hilarious).

This is supposed to be a "detector" that can "find a hot meteorite" that landed on earth.

[image]

Except it's plainly the board out of a router. A cable variant of whatever router, since the DSL interface isn't populated.  The closest I have come to it is that it's a D-Link router.  A Mediatek MIPS chip in the middle, with a DRAM chip below it, and the WiFi interface under the shield.

Oh, and a few LEDs stuck through a bit of plastic wired to the battery pack in the bottom left.

Hilarious!

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I was going to post this as a question myself, but didn't know where to do so...

In [Silicon Valley](http://Silicon%20Valley%20S02E03) S02E03, Gilforth is reading the Arduino Projects book and has an Uno and a shield on it. At the risk of sneaking in a question within an answer, what shield is it?

[image: Silicon Valley S02E03]

Comment: Looks like some LCD shield of some form.

Comment: I thought that, maybe a 1602? But without the buttons on the ROBOT shield.

Comment: Probably, yes. It is probably white on blue as well.